# Is a monotone function in $[a,b]$ NOT integrable?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've read many proofs that a monotone function on $[a,b]$ is (Riemann) integrable. If the function is $f(x)=x$ for every rational number and **undefined** for any non-rational number?

I know that the Dirichlet function is not integrable because it's not continuous at any point, but so is this monotonic function, so isn't this function also non-integrable?

So I know that I'm wrong just don't really understand why.

Comment: Your function is not a function on $[a,b]$; at most it's a function on $[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question doesn't make sense. If the function isn't defined on all of $[a,b]$, you cannot judge whether or not it is integrable on $[a,b]$.

To answer a broader question: a function defined on an interval $[a,b]$ is Riemann integrable if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere (here 'almost everywhere' has a technical meaning, and it turns out that there is a theorem saying that monotone functions are continuous almost everywhere, so they are integrable). If you take $f(x) = x$ on the rationals and redefine it to be something else on the irrationals, then it will be discontinuous everywhere except possibly on a very small set $($e.g., if $f$ is defined on $[0,1]$ and $f(x) = x$ for rational $x$ and $f(x) = x^2$ for irrational $x$, then $f$ is discontinuous everywhere in $[0,1]$ except at $x = 0$ and $x= 1)$, and thus fail to be integrable. But, as I said before, if you leave it undefined somewhere in the domain, the question doesn't make sense.